# No me funciona con los binarios

Tags: c++

Este código para una matriz binaria debe sacar la R.antisimetrica sin embargo tras varias pruebas no da a ninguna matriz como antisimetrica

```
 //Relacion antisimetrica
 for (int i=0;i<filas;i++) {
  for (int j=0;j<columnas;j++) {
   if (numeros[i][j] != -numeros[j][i]) {/*Condicional que compara los datos en la matriz y determina si es antisimetrica*/
    cout << "La matriz: No es ANTISIMETRICA" << endl;
    cout<<"\n";
    cout << "elemento correspondiente no es inverso aditivo"<<endl;
    cout<<"\n";
    valor3=false;
    break;
   }
  }
  if (valor3==false)
   break;
 }
 if (valor3){
  cout<<"La matriz: ES ANTISIMETRICA"<<endl;
  cout<<"\n";
 }
```

Comment: ¿Puedes ser más claro? No entiendo el problema.

Comment: estoy haciendo un programa con matrices binarias el cual debe sacar si tiene o no tiene n relacion en este caso la anti simétrica la cual indica si los elementos a la izquierda de la diagonal de la matriz es opuesto , al ponerlo en practico el código de arriba , ninguna probabilidad la arroja como anti simétrica , y pues pensándolo bien la matriz no puede tener números negativos ya que la variable que guarda los elementos esta definida como booleano